# Cannot intent to specific page of apps from notification builder using FCM (android)

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

im beginner of using FCM to make notification in my android apps. I successed to make notification with FCM in my android apps but when i did not open my apps and there was a notification and i clicked it, it cannot intent to specific page should be, it just show the main page of my apps. But when i opened my apps, and then there was notification and i clicked it, it show the specific page. Even though, i have make my apps always running in backgroud. What is the problem? Can i make my apps intent to specific page should be although im not open my apps? Please help.. 
Thankyou...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yor MainActivity is entry point of your app, so if your app not startup, click the notification will invoke it first, if you want to jump to spefic page, you should add some jump flag to your notification message body, so when the mainactivity startup, you can check the flag and jump to correct page.